# How do I update selected value in DropdownButtonFormfield reliable when the list changes (shrinks) in a Streambuilder

Tags: flutter, flutter-streambuilder, flutter-dropdownbuttonformfield

Following code fills a DropdownButtonFormField with items (initial selection is null), when user selects a selections which is i.e. index of 15. All works ok so far. "Suddenly" `Streambuilder` refreshs list with less items than 15, lets say 10. And tries to "redraw" the dropdownButtonFormField and provides another index (null or 0), code suddenly fails with following:

[image]

How do I reliably change the selected value to less than provided list, when it seems that my new `value` is not taken into consideration ? Or is there a bug in DropdownButtonFormField according to changing the selected value?

```
Expanded(
 child: Padding(
   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
   child: StreamBuilder(
     stream: globals.mPortalDatabase.getGoogleAddresses().watch(),
     builder: (context, snapshot) {
       if(snapshot.hasError){
         return DropdownButtonFormField<int>(
           decoration: InputDecoration(
             label: Text("Assignment location"),
             border: OutlineInputBorder()
           ),
           items: [
             DropdownMenuItem(child: Text(snapshot.error.toString(), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),))
           ],
           onChanged: null,
         );
       }
       if(snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.waiting){
         return DropdownButtonFormField<int>(
           decoration: InputDecoration(
             label: Text("Assignment location"),
             border: OutlineInputBorder()
           ),
           items: [],
           onChanged: null,
         );
       }

       List<DropdownMenuItem<int>> dropdownMenuItemList=[];

       if(snapshot.hasData){
         var googleDataElements = snapshot.data;
         print("Data present for dropdown = ${googleDataElements?.length}");
         if(googleDataElements!=null){
           if(googleDataElements.isNotEmpty){
             dropdownMenuItemList = List.generate(googleDataElements.length, (index) {
               return DropdownMenuItem<int>(
                 child: Text("${googleDataElements[index].formattedAddress}; ${googleDataElements[index].geometryLocationType}"),
                 value: index,
               );
             });
           }
           if(selectedAddressIndex!=null){
             if(selectedAddressIndex!<dropdownMenuItemList.length){
               if(googleDataElements[selectedAddressIndex!].formattedAddress!=selectedAddressItem){
                 selectedAddressIndex = null;
               }
             } else {
               selectedAddressIndex = null;
             }
           } 
         } else {
           selectedAddressIndex = null;
         }

       } else {
         print("No data present for dropdown");
       }
       
       print("Data present for dropdown = ${dropdownMenuItemList.length}");
       print("selectedAddressIndex = $selectedAddressIndex");
       
       return DropdownButtonFormField<int>(
         value: selectedAddressIndex,
         decoration: InputDecoration(
           label: Text("Assignment location"),
           border: OutlineInputBorder(),
         ),
         items: dropdownMenuItemList,
         onChanged: (value){

       }
     );
   }
 ),
),
),
```

Typical log content, as you see, the `selectedAddressIndex` is changed, but fails anyway...:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Flutter is not detecting that your `DropdownButtonFormField` widget has changed when it is rebuilding the tree. It can be fixed by providing a Key to your widget which shall change when the stream returns new data.

The easiest way is creating a **`ValueKey`** created with unique values from the list of elements, for example:

```dart
final Key dropdownKey = ValueKey(googleDataElements.fold("", (v, e) => "$v-${e.geohash}"))
```

And then provide that key in the constructor of the `DropdownButtonFormField` widget.